# nested if - else statements -ocaml

Tags: ocaml

can we do multiple operations inside our if-else loop in ocaml?

I am trying to do the following:

```
let rec appendtolist n list b  =

    let f x =

        if ( b < 0 ) then x

        else if (b == 0) then ((appendtocode n (List.hd list) ) (b-1)) (* THIS LINE *)

        else ((appendtocode n (List.hd list)) :: (appendtolist n (List.tl list) (b-1)) )

    in

    f list

    ;;
```

I get a complain by the compiler on the line which I made bold that :

This expression is not a function, it cannot be applied

I want to call my function when `b==0` and also decrement value of `b`.

How could I do it in this case?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same error as [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299102/nested-if-else-loop-error-ocaml).

You're evaluating

```
appendtocode n (List.hd list)
```

which returns a value, which is *not* a function. Then you try to call it with `b-1` as its argument, but since it's not a function, you can't do that.

> I want to call my function when b==0 and also decrement value of b.

Decrement `b` for whom? `b` is an argument to the function `appendtolist`, so if you call `appendtolist` recursively, you can supply a new argument for `b`, which is what you're doing in the `else` case and that works fine. But in the `then` case you're not calling `appendtolist`. You're only calling `appendtocode` and `appendtocode` has not third argument `b`. So passing it `b-1` simply makes no sense.

My guess is that your program will work just fine if you remove the `b-1`.

PS: This issue is entirely unrelated to nested `if`s.

Comment: appendtocode returns a string. I want to call it and also decrement value of b.

Comment: gr8! I just removed the b-1 and made a call to appendlist again. worked gr8!!! thank you :)sorry for confusion. still trying to learn this language :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess:

The expression given as

```
( appendtocode n (List.hd list) )
```

returns something which is not a function, and hence you can't apply the value of (b-1) to it which is what you are trying to do. To verify, you can look up the type of `appendtocode` and see it it can take two or three curried arguments.

Comment: I do not want to apply b-1 to appendtocode. I just want to decrement b-1 in this function.